# MySql Unicode collation utf8mb4_german2_ci not found *** German umlaut collation ***

Tags: mysql, collation, diacritics, character-set

After installing MySql 5.7 , I cannot find this collation:
`utf8mb4_german2_ci`

The worklog 4013 mentions that "Unicode german2 collation" will be there from Server 5.6  ("Affects: Server-5.6 ; Status is: Complete ) 
https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=4013

The new collations will be:

`utf8_german2_ci`,
`ucs2_german2_ci`,
`utf8mb4_german2_ci`,
`utf16_german2_ci`,
`utf32_german2_ci`

In my databases (mysql 5.6) I cannot find the new collations neither. Is the worklog 4013 only a draft or proposal ?!

Answer (score 1):

In MySql-Workbench v6.3 the collation `utf8mb4_german2_ci` is missing from the dropDown.

In phpMyAdmin `utf8mb4_german2_ci` exists.